# Do deleted Google Chat contacts still see when I'm available?

Tags: google-talk

I deleted a contact from my Google Chat contacts list. Can they still see when I'm available?

Do they get any notice that I've deleted them from my gchat list?

I'm just wondering if they can see me at all when I'm signed into Gmail even though I've removed them from my side.

Answer (score 4):

They won't get a notice that you've removed them from your contacts list. They should only then see your icon as offline.

To make certain they can't see or contact you, [you should block them.](http://www.google.com/support/talk/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=23941)

1. Right-click on the person's name, and select **Remove Name...**
2. Check the box next to "Block this person" in the dialogue box that appears, and click **OK.**

When you block someone, they can no longer talk with your or even see if you're online until or unless you unblock them.